# Jquery mobile android app - rendered elements not aligned with tap/click area

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile based app running via Phonegap on Android.  Everything works correctly, but I have an odd problem with the buttons contained within a dynamically loaded panel.  Basically, if you try to tap one button, the one below it on the screen is tapped.  It's like what is rendered on the screen doesn't actually line up with where the buttons are.

For example, if I tap on "A" below, "B" will fire.

```
*** A ***
*** B ***
*** C ***
```

Now it's not happening **every** time, but sometimes.

My code is as follows:

```
// for every page
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){                

    // the following code creates the left panel (navigation) on all pages
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#left_panel').remove();

    $('<div>').attr({'id':'left_panel','data-role':'panel','data-display':'push'}).appendTo($(this));
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#left_panel').panel();

    // this loads the content of the panel
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#left_panel').load('includes/left_panel.html', function() {

        $.mobile.activePage.find('#left_panel').trigger("create");
        $( "#main_nav" ).listview("refresh");

    });

    // this adds the click event to the show navigation button in the header
    $(document).off('click', '#open_panel_button').on('click', '#open_panel_button', function(){   
         $.mobile.activePage.find('#left_panel').panel("open");       
    });

});
```

---

```
// includes/left_panel.html
<div>
    <h3>Navigation</h3>
    <ul id="main_nav" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#aPage">*** A ***</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bPage">*** B ***</a></li>
        <li><a href="#cPage">*** C ***</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

I know this is quite a vague question, but I've honestly had this in my app for months and I can't figure out how to fix it.  I'm just wondering if anyone on here has experienced anything similar where rendered elements in jQuery Mobile don't line up with where the click/tap area is.  To me, it's like I need to refresh the page once the panel is displayed or something.

Additional info, if useful:

- The app is only ever used on Android 2.3.1 and 4.0.3
- PhoneGap/Cordova version 2.9.0
- jQuery v1.11.1
- jQuery Mobile 1.4.5

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to, but couldn't work out how to do this bit in a fiddle: `.load('includes/left_panel.html', function() {`